# How do you delete (or fill with specific values) a static n-dimension array?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
const int ROWS = 3;
const int COLUMNS = 4;

void fillArray(double a[ROWS][COLUMNS], double value);
void deleteArray(double a[ROWS][COLUMNS]);

int main () {
    double a[ROWS][COLUMNS];
    fillArray(a, 0);
    deleteArray(a);
}
```

Comment: `memset(a, 0, sizeof(a));` to fill and don't delete stack variables.

Comment: `sizeof(a)`... will that correctly determine the size of an n-dimension array?

Comment: ...and how do you insert code blocks in comments? :)

Comment: @ruslik: depending on keyboard layout. It's shift+ `´` here. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In C++, how do you delete (or fill with specific values) a static n-dimension array?

In C++ we generally do not use arrays. We use `std::vector`.
You can use [`memset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/) or [`std::fill`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/) to fill the array with specific values.
BTW you can use `delete` on dynamically allocated arrays not on static ones.

```
 memset( a, 0 ,ROWS * COLUMNS * sizeof( double ));
 or
 std::fill(&a[0][0], &a[0][0]+sizeof(a)/sizeof(double), 0);
```

Comment: Okay, but what about my question? How do you delete a static array (not a vector, not a dynamic array)?

Comment: @Andrey : You cannot use `delete` on statically allocated arrays. Any attempt to do that would invoke Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: So in other words I would not delete stack variables... but what about filling a static array with default values? Just n for loops, or is there a better way?

Comment: To clarify, there's no point to deleting a static array. You only need to worry about memory management with dynamically allocated things.

Comment: Your example works but your parameters are ordered incorrectly:

Comment: @Andrew : Oh God! I need more coffee. BTW thanks I corrected the mistake.

Comment: Should be `std::fill(&a[0][0], &a[0][0]+sizeof(a)/sizeof(double), 0);` shouldn't it?  Or even better(in my opinion) `std::fill_n(&a[0][0], sizeof(a)/sizeof(double), 0);`

Answer (score 2):

You can `delete` only an object created by `new` (and that object will be allocated in the heap). What do you mean by "deleting a static POD variable"? It has no sense:

1) It doesn't have any destructor to perform additional tasks before freeing the memory,

2) The stack memory will be "freed" as you exit the current block.

And to set it: either loop, either simple `memset(a, 0, sizeof(a));` .

Also, the array in your example is not `static`.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/) is what is generally used for C++ arrays (especially when you're new at it). One of `vector`'s constructors will fill it for you to:

```
std::vector<type> myVector(initialSize, defaultValue);
```

If you want multidimensional, you could do a vector of vectors, or [`boost::multi_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html):

```
boost::multi_array<type, numberOfDimensions> myArray(boost::extents[firstSize][secondSize][thirdSize]);
```

In that case, you'll need to use the multiple-for-loops approach, because it doesn't seem to have a constructor that does that.

EDIT: Actually you can use `std::vector` to make a multidimensional array with default values:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > a(3, std::vector<double>(4, 0));
```

Where 3 is the number of rows, 4 is the number of columns and 0 is the default value.

What it's doing is create a vector of vectors with 3 rows, where the default value for each row is a vector with 4 zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

Filling arrays in C++ is the same as filling them using C, namely nested for loops

```
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        a[i][j] = 0
```

Arrays aren't "deleted" but they can use `free` if they've been allocated on the heap (if they've been allocated on the stack within a function, this is unnecessary).

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    free(a[i]);
free(a);
```

Comment: The first part of this answer is fine, but the second part is misleading. Heap arrays (created with `new` or `malloc`) need to be deallocated with `free(myArray)` or `delete(myArray)`, but stack arrays (like the one in the question) don't, and in some cases it would cause problems.

Comment: @Brendan: Whoops, I just assumed it was allocated on the heap. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use std::fill

```
#include <algorithm>
```

And then your implementation is simply:

```
std::fill(&a[0][0], &a[0][0]+sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0][0], value);
```

You don't delete the array since it is stack allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the code you posted seems confused. What is it that you think "deleteArray" is supposed to do? 'a' is an auto variable and therefore cannot be deleted or freed.

Secondly, wrap your array in a class. There is a nice one in the [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.10) that you can start with, but it can be improved. The first improvement is to use a vector rather than newing a block of memory. Then std::fill can be used to fill the array.